# flutter fileshare default OS language settings

Tags: ios, flutter, fileshare

I am implementing the file sharing function using FlutterfileShare. The problem here is that when I press File Share, the default language of IOS is set to English. I want to express it in Korean, but there is only one part where Korean is displayed. To solve this problem, I also looked for flutter file share github issue, but it is not a problem with the package.
The method I used was 1. I changed all the language settings on the device to Korean. 2. I added a code that handles multilingual. (Korean).
But even though I applied the above 2 methods, it doesn't work out. Please let me know a good way!! Have a nice day Thank you

[image]

Comment: I solved this problem.
This is Because, i'm not set info-plist settings.